# Pinescript loop through drawings

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I'm trying to write a code in pinescript that will loop through an array that have price levels in it. It then draws a box based on set parameters. My issue is this - I'm getting a ton of duplicate lines as it cycles through the loop. If I have 10 items in the array, the first line/box gets drawn 10 times over. How do I avoid that?

```
for i = 0 to array.size(myarray) - 1
    var box _box = na
    _box := box.new(bar_index[100], x, bar_index[0], x + y, color, border, style, extend.both, xloc.bar_index, color.new(color.red,70))
    box.delete(_box[i])
```

Please ignore x, y, border, color, style within the box.new. I'm simplifying here.
How do fix this to only create one box per i ? Thank you very much

Comment: You can declare `myBoxes` array with same number of elements that `myarray` has. In the loop you can create and put box id into `myBoxes` if it haven't it yet or just modify existing one.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by adding an if statement before the loop. This way it only loads on last bar and avoid looping over from history

```
if (barstate.islastconfirmedhistory)
```